# Build and Deploy error using Github Pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I am creating a Website using HTML, CSS and JS and using a GitHub repository. I've recently made some changes to the index.html and stylesheet.css files and when I try to commit, there are two erros that pop up. Note that the code does not have any errors in it.

These are the errors:
[Build Error GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1wkX.png)
[Deploy Job Skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdTqY.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance.

```
/* Font Imports */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap");

/* Fonts */

h1 {
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}
/* Placeholder */

* {
  background-color: #eae6e3;
  color: #353535;
}

/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container-test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 90vh;
  }

  .container-test h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .container-test h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .container-test img {
    height: 10vh;
  }
}

/* Tablet */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .container-test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 90vh;
  }

  .container-test h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
  }

  .container-test h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  .container-test img {
    height: 15vh;
  }
}

/* Desktop */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container-test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 90vh;
  }

  .container-test h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 5.5rem;
  }

  .container-test h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  .container-test img {
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error references Git submodules, which are independent of what else you have in your repository, and shouldn't be related to any HTML and CSS changes.